# Prove that if $\sum_k k^2 |a_k|^2 < \infty$ then $\sum_k |a_k| < \infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

During class, the professor made the following statement, but did not prove it.

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 |a_k|^2 < \infty$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k| < \infty$.

How does one prove that this is indeed true?

Here is what I'm stuck on. So since  the first series converges,
I get that $k^2|a_k| \to 0$, hence, $|a_k|^2 < \frac{1}{k^2}$ for a $k$ sufficiently large. Now, what I'd like to do it to claim that
$$|a_k| \leq \frac{1}{k^{1+\varepsilon}}$$

Therefore, I'd get that my series would be dominated by
$$\sum |a_k|\leq \sum \frac{1}{k^{1+\varepsilon}} <\infty$$
I have some issues with this approach, first the claim that $|a_k| < \frac{1}{k}$ does not seem quite right, and I'm also not sure I could claim that $|a_k| \leq \frac{1}{k^{1+\varepsilon}}$.

Sorry if this question seems easy, perhaps the very simple solution is simply going over my head.